vertical alignment of text in multicols environment
I am trying to get the text in both columns to align vertically.
I've been trying to eliminate the spaces/skips I'm aware of (parskip, before/after section skip).
After beginning the section 'Results' the alignment is off. The figure environment I've used, the caption and the subsection seem to work fine, being spaced solely using multiples of baselineskip.
But there seems to be some space inserted before the new section.
MWE:
\documentclass[ 11pt, a4paper]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm, includehead, headheight=0.5cm]{geometry}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\fontfamily{lmss}\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off, font={sf, bf}, labelfont=bf,    
    labelsep=period, margin=0cm,skip=0pt, belowskip=0pt]{caption} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{Figure2col}[1]
  {\par\noindent\minipage[][#1\baselineskip][t]{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=false,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=0pt]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  runin=true,
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterskip=30pt]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=0pt]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\setkomafont{section}{\centering \Large \bfseries \scshape}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large \bfseries \scshape}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\section{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[3]
\subsection{Some Intro Part}
    \lipsum[4-8]
\section{Results}
    \lipsum[3-4]
\begin{Figure2col}{12}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{Figure2col}
\begin{minipage}[][1\baselineskip][c]{\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}[Figure A]{\textit{Figure A}}
\end{minipage}
\subsection{More Results}
    \lipsum[3-5]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}

alignment_1
alignment_2
I've tried putting \nointerlineskip before \section{Results}, but that didn't help. Changing the fontsize of the section header to \normalfont also didn't do anything.
In the actual code I'm placing hrules and baselineskips around the section, but since this didn't alter anything, I left it out here.
I've been trying to find answers all over the place, but nothing has worked. It is driving me insane.
Any suggestion would be extremely appreciated!

Maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/topic/typeset-grid

Thanks for the tip! Adding a \gridenv does force the lines into alignment. However, it seems to be incompatible with many additional formatting options I've used.
